# wordpress stdClass Object elements how to print php string

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, string, std

**How to print option under selection_items**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 19
    [is_core_field] => 0
    [order_num] => 19
    [name] => Accommodation Amenities
    [slug] => accommodation_amenities
    [description] => 
    [type] => checkbox
    [icon_image] => 
    [is_required] => 0
    [is_configuration_page] => 1
    [is_search_configuration_page] => 1
    [is_ordered] => 0
    [is_hide_name] => 0
    [for_admin_only] => 0
    [on_exerpt_page] => 0
    [on_listing_page] => 1
    [on_search_form] => 1
    [on_map] => 0
    [advanced_search_form] => 0
    [categories] => a:6:{i:0;s:4:"2801";i:1;s:4:"2874";i:2;s:4:"2852";i:3;s:4:"2849";i:4;s:4:"2850";i:5;s:4:"2851";}
    [options] => a:4:{s:15:"selection_items";a:153:{i:5;s:23:"24-Hour Guest Reception";i:60;s:16:"24-Hour Security";i:138;s:18:"Accessible Parking";i:55;s:7:"Adapter";i:122;s:17:"Additional Toilet";i:30;s:16:"Air Conditioning";i:123;s:17:"Allergy-free room";i:142;s:11:"ATM On-Site";i:61;s:27:"Babysitting/child services ";i:46;s:7:"Balcony";i:48;s:8:"Bathrobe";i:45;s:7:"Bathtub";i:39;s:10:"Bar/Lounge";i:148;s:10:"Beachfront";i:84;s:9:"Body Soap";i:35;s:12:"Bridal Suite";i:13;s:17:"Business Services";i:25;s:18:"Cable/Satellite TV";i:27;s:4:"CCTV";i:56;s:20:"Cleaning Commodities";i:57;s:12:"Clothes Rack";i:14;s:23:"Complimentary Breakfast";i:6;s:24:"Complimentary Toiletries";i:32;s:9:"Concierge";i:116;s:11:"Conditioner";i:20;s:25:"Cribs & Cots for Children";i:22;s:19:"Curated Experiences";i:21;s:13:"Custom Offers";i:78;s:23:"Designated Smoking Area";i:132;s:8:"Detached";i:90;s:11:"Dining Area";i:118;s:23:"Drying Rack for Clothes";i:64;s:15:"Electric Kettle";i:11;s:20:"Electronics Chargers";i:36;s:15:"Elevator Access";i:114;s:35:"Entire Unit located on Ground Floor";i:17;s:25:"Exercise Facilities (Gym)";i:40;s:23:"Executive Lounge Access";i:96;s:26:"Express Check in/Check Out";i:92;s:12:"Family Rooms";i:49;s:3:"Fan";i:113;s:14:"Feather Pillow";i:44;s:17:"Fire Extinguisher";i:155;s:13:"First Aid Kit";i:8;s:17:"Flexible Checkout";i:152;s:44:"Food can be Delivered to Guest Accommodation";i:26;s:19:"Free Early Check-in";i:3;s:12:"Free Parking";i:2;s:9:"Free WIFI";i:77;s:6:"Fruits";i:93;s:6:"Garden";i:130;s:11:"Garden View";i:71;s:9:"Gift shop";i:115;s:5:"Grill";i:83;s:9:"Hairdryer";i:131;s:38:"Hand sanitizer in guest accommodation ";i:124;s:26:"Hardwood or Parquet Floors";i:7;s:17:"Healthy Breakfast";i:149;s:9:"Hot Water";i:157;s:7:"Heating";i:24;s:12:"Housekeeping";i:58;s:21:"Hypoallergenic pillow";i:103;s:23:"Increased Accessibility";i:125;s:20:"Inner Courtyard View";i:62;s:32:"Interconnected room(s) available";i:137;s:22:"Iron and Ironing Board";i:99;s:15:"Ironing Service";i:38;s:15:"Key Card Access";i:41;s:10:"Kids Meals";i:128;s:19:"Kid-friendly Buffet";i:156;s:28:"Kid activities/ Kid Friendly";i:33;s:11:"Kitchenette";i:94;s:13:"Landmark View";i:150;s:11:"Laptop Safe";i:15;s:16:"Laundry Services";i:67;s:6:"Linens";i:146;s:7:"Lockers";i:76;s:26:"Meeting/Banquet facilities";i:29;s:9:"Microwave";i:63;s:13:"Mountain View";i:89;s:12:"Mosquito Net";i:18;s:9:"Newspaper";i:54;s:15:"No Pets Allowed";i:120;s:22:"No Single-Use Plastics";i:53;s:10:"No Smoking";i:109;s:18:"Non-Feather Pillow";i:119;s:27:"Non-Smoking Rooms Available";i:28;s:18:"On-site Restaurant";i:70;s:17:"Outdoor furniture";i:98;s:19:"Outdoor Dining Area";i:121;s:4:"Oven";i:153;s:17:"Outdoor Fireplace";i:95;s:14:"Packed Lunches";i:80;s:11:"Pants Press";i:23;s:18:"Pet-friendly Rooms";i:105;s:11:"Picnic Area";i:85;s:25:"Physical Distancing Rules";i:133;s:29:"Private Apartment in Building";i:134;s:16:"Private Bathroom";i:136;s:14:"Private Beach ";i:91;s:26:"Private Check-In/Check-Out";i:72;s:16:"Private Entrance";i:140;s:17:"Quiet Street View";i:144;s:10:"Restaurant";i:10;s:12:"Refrigerator";i:129;s:10:"River View";i:145;s:7:"Rooftop";i:4;s:12:"Room Service";i:65;s:4:"Safe";i:34;s:18:"Safety Deposit Box";i:147;s:5:"Sauna";i:73;s:8:"Sea view";i:74;s:12:"Seating Area";i:100;s:15:"Secured Parking";i:112;s:13:"Semi-detached";i:101;s:15:"Shared Bathroom";i:102;s:21:"Shared Lounge/TV Area";i:66;s:7:"Shampoo";i:106;s:9:"Shoeshine";i:68;s:6:"Shower";i:69;s:10:"Shower cap";i:31;s:15:"Shuttle Service";i:37;s:12:"Smoke Alarms";i:81;s:9:"Snack Bar";i:88;s:19:"Socket near the bed";i:50;s:4:"Sofa";i:16;s:24:"Spa & Wellness Amenities";i:59;s:18:"Special Diet Menus";i:154;s:66:"Staff follow all safety protocols as directed by local authorities";i:19;s:18:"Storage Available ";i:111;s:8:"Stovetop";i:97;s:14:"Street Parking";i:9;s:13:"Swimming Pool";i:86;s:16:"Tea/coffee maker";i:43;s:9:"Telephone";i:51;s:13:"Terrace/Patio";i:107;s:17:"Tile/Marble Floor";i:108;s:7:"Toaster";i:126;s:12:"Toilet Paper";i:139;s:10:"Toiletries";i:42;s:6:"Towels";i:143;s:2:"TV";i:75;s:10:"Trash Cans";i:117;s:33:"Upper Floors accessible by Stairs";i:104;s:13:"Valet Parking";i:151;s:19:"VIP Room Facilities";i:47;s:14:"Walk-in Shower";i:141;s:15:"Washing Machine";i:52;s:15:"Wardrobe/Closet";i:79;s:16:"Wedding services";i:82;s:6:"Window";i:135;s:12:"Wine Glasses";i:1;s:18:"Wheel Chair Access";}s:11:"icon_images";a:153:{i:5;s:0:"";i:60;s:0:"";i:138;s:0:"";i:55;s:0:"";i:122;s:0:"";i:30;s:0:"";i:123;s:0:"";i:142;s:0:"";i:61;s:0:"";i:46;s:0:"";i:48;s:0:"";i:45;s:0:"";i:39;s:0:"";i:148;s:0:"";i:84;s:0:"";i:35;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:25;s:0:"";i:27;s:0:"";i:56;s:0:"";i:57;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:32;s:0:"";i:116;s:0:"";i:20;s:0:"";i:22;s:0:"";i:21;s:0:"";i:78;s:0:"";i:132;s:0:"";i:90;s:0:"";i:118;s:0:"";i:64;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:36;s:0:"";i:114;s:0:"";i:17;s:0:"";i:40;s:0:"";i:96;s:0:"";i:92;s:0:"";i:49;s:0:"";i:113;s:0:"";i:44;s:0:"";i:155;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:152;s:0:"";i:26;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:77;s:0:"";i:93;s:0:"";i:130;s:0:"";i:71;s:0:"";i:115;s:0:"";i:83;s:0:"";i:131;s:0:"";i:124;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:149;s:0:"";i:157;s:0:"";i:24;s:0:"";i:58;s:0:"";i:103;s:0:"";i:125;s:0:"";i:62;s:0:"";i:137;s:0:"";i:99;s:0:"";i:38;s:0:"";i:41;s:0:"";i:128;s:0:"";i:156;s:0:"";i:33;s:0:"";i:94;s:0:"";i:150;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";i:67;s:0:"";i:146;s:0:"";i:76;s:0:"";i:29;s:0:"";i:63;s:0:"";i:89;s:0:"";i:18;s:0:"";i:54;s:0:"";i:120;s:0:"";i:53;s:0:"";i:109;s:0:"";i:119;s:0:"";i:28;s:0:"";i:70;s:0:"";i:98;s:0:"";i:121;s:0:"";i:153;s:0:"";i:95;s:0:"";i:80;s:0:"";i:23;s:0:"";i:105;s:0:"";i:85;s:0:"";i:133;s:0:"";i:134;s:0:"";i:136;s:0:"";i:91;s:0:"";i:72;s:0:"";i:140;s:0:"";i:144;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:129;s:0:"";i:145;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:65;s:0:"";i:34;s:0:"";i:147;s:0:"";i:73;s:0:"";i:74;s:0:"";i:100;s:0:"";i:112;s:0:"";i:101;s:0:"";i:102;s:0:"";i:66;s:0:"";i:106;s:0:"";i:68;s:0:"";i:69;s:0:"";i:31;s:0:"";i:37;s:0:"";i:81;s:0:"";i:88;s:0:"";i:50;s:0:"";i:16;s:0:"";i:59;s:0:"";i:154;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";i:111;s:0:"";i:97;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:86;s:0:"";i:43;s:0:"";i:51;s:0:"";i:107;s:0:"";i:108;s:0:"";i:126;s:0:"";i:139;s:0:"";i:42;s:0:"";i:143;s:0:"";i:75;s:0:"";i:117;s:0:"";i:104;s:0:"";i:151;s:0:"";i:47;s:0:"";i:141;s:0:"";i:52;s:0:"";i:79;s:0:"";i:82;s:0:"";i:135;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";}s:17:"how_display_items";s:7:"checked";s:14:"columns_number";s:1:"3";}
    [search_options] => 
    [group_id] => 0
)
```

How can i get the result from options =>"selection_items". Please guide me, i am using wordpress. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

WordPress serializes arrays and objexts when stored in the database.

You need to [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the value of `options`. For example:

```
unserialize($array['options']);
```

WordPress also includes a [maybe_unserialize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) function that does the same job, but it includes a condition to only unserialize data that has been serialized.

```
maybe_unserialize($array['options']);
```

Once you've unserialized the `options` it will return the following array:

```
array (
  'selection_items' => 
  array (
    5 => '24-Hour Guest Reception',
    60 => '24-Hour Security',
    138 => 'Accessible Parking',
    55 => 'Adapter',
    122 => 'Additional Toilet',
    30 => 'Air Conditioning',
    123 => 'Allergy-free room',
    142 => 'ATM On-Site',
    61 => 'Babysitting/child services ',
    46 => 'Balcony',
    48 => 'Bathrobe',
    45 => 'Bathtub',
    39 => 'Bar/Lounge',
    148 => 'Beachfront',
    84 => 'Body Soap',
    35 => 'Bridal Suite',
    13 => 'Business Services',
    25 => 'Cable/Satellite TV',
    27 => 'CCTV',
    56 => 'Cleaning Commodities',
    57 => 'Clothes Rack',
    14 => 'Complimentary Breakfast',
    6 => 'Complimentary Toiletries',
    32 => 'Concierge',
    116 => 'Conditioner',
    20 => 'Cribs & Cots for Children',
    22 => 'Curated Experiences',
    21 => 'Custom Offers',
    78 => 'Designated Smoking Area',
    132 => 'Detached',
    90 => 'Dining Area',
    118 => 'Drying Rack for Clothes',
    64 => 'Electric Kettle',
    11 => 'Electronics Chargers',
    36 => 'Elevator Access',
    114 => 'Entire Unit located on Ground Floor',
    17 => 'Exercise Facilities (Gym)',
    40 => 'Executive Lounge Access',
    96 => 'Express Check in/Check Out',
    92 => 'Family Rooms',
    49 => 'Fan',
    113 => 'Feather Pillow',
    44 => 'Fire Extinguisher',
    155 => 'First Aid Kit',
    8 => 'Flexible Checkout',
    152 => 'Food can be Delivered to Guest Accommodation',
    26 => 'Free Early Check-in',
    3 => 'Free Parking',
    2 => 'Free WIFI',
    77 => 'Fruits',
    93 => 'Garden',
    130 => 'Garden View',
    71 => 'Gift shop',
    115 => 'Grill',
    83 => 'Hairdryer',
    131 => 'Hand sanitizer in guest accommodation ',
    124 => 'Hardwood or Parquet Floors',
    7 => 'Healthy Breakfast',
    149 => 'Hot Water',
    157 => 'Heating',
    24 => 'Housekeeping',
    58 => 'Hypoallergenic pillow',
    103 => 'Increased Accessibility',
    125 => 'Inner Courtyard View',
    62 => 'Interconnected room(s) available',
    137 => 'Iron and Ironing Board',
    99 => 'Ironing Service',
    38 => 'Key Card Access',
    41 => 'Kids Meals',
    128 => 'Kid-friendly Buffet',
    156 => 'Kid activities/ Kid Friendly',
    33 => 'Kitchenette',
    94 => 'Landmark View',
    150 => 'Laptop Safe',
    15 => 'Laundry Services',
    67 => 'Linens',
    146 => 'Lockers',
    76 => 'Meeting/Banquet facilities',
    29 => 'Microwave',
    63 => 'Mountain View',
    89 => 'Mosquito Net',
    18 => 'Newspaper',
    54 => 'No Pets Allowed',
    120 => 'No Single-Use Plastics',
    53 => 'No Smoking',
    109 => 'Non-Feather Pillow',
    119 => 'Non-Smoking Rooms Available',
    28 => 'On-site Restaurant',
    70 => 'Outdoor furniture',
    98 => 'Outdoor Dining Area',
    121 => 'Oven',
    153 => 'Outdoor Fireplace',
    95 => 'Packed Lunches',
    80 => 'Pants Press',
    23 => 'Pet-friendly Rooms',
    105 => 'Picnic Area',
    85 => 'Physical Distancing Rules',
    133 => 'Private Apartment in Building',
    134 => 'Private Bathroom',
    136 => 'Private Beach ',
    91 => 'Private Check-In/Check-Out',
    72 => 'Private Entrance',
    140 => 'Quiet Street View',
    144 => 'Restaurant',
    10 => 'Refrigerator',
    129 => 'River View',
    145 => 'Rooftop',
    4 => 'Room Service',
    65 => 'Safe',
    34 => 'Safety Deposit Box',
    147 => 'Sauna',
    73 => 'Sea view',
    74 => 'Seating Area',
    100 => 'Secured Parking',
    112 => 'Semi-detached',
    101 => 'Shared Bathroom',
    102 => 'Shared Lounge/TV Area',
    66 => 'Shampoo',
    106 => 'Shoeshine',
    68 => 'Shower',
    69 => 'Shower cap',
    31 => 'Shuttle Service',
    37 => 'Smoke Alarms',
    81 => 'Snack Bar',
    88 => 'Socket near the bed',
    50 => 'Sofa',
    16 => 'Spa & Wellness Amenities',
    59 => 'Special Diet Menus',
    154 => 'Staff follow all safety protocols as directed by local authorities',
    19 => 'Storage Available ',
    111 => 'Stovetop',
    97 => 'Street Parking',
    9 => 'Swimming Pool',
    86 => 'Tea/coffee maker',
    43 => 'Telephone',
    51 => 'Terrace/Patio',
    107 => 'Tile/Marble Floor',
    108 => 'Toaster',
    126 => 'Toilet Paper',
    139 => 'Toiletries',
    42 => 'Towels',
    143 => 'TV',
    75 => 'Trash Cans',
    117 => 'Upper Floors accessible by Stairs',
    104 => 'Valet Parking',
    151 => 'VIP Room Facilities',
    47 => 'Walk-in Shower',
    141 => 'Washing Machine',
    52 => 'Wardrobe/Closet',
    79 => 'Wedding services',
    82 => 'Window',
    135 => 'Wine Glasses',
    1 => 'Wheel Chair Access',
  ),
  'icon_images' => 
  array (
    5 => '',
    60 => '',
    138 => '',
    55 => '',
    122 => '',
    30 => '',
    123 => '',
    142 => '',
    61 => '',
    46 => '',
    48 => '',
    45 => '',
    39 => '',
    148 => '',
    84 => '',
    35 => '',
    13 => '',
    25 => '',
    27 => '',
    56 => '',
    57 => '',
    14 => '',
    6 => '',
    32 => '',
    116 => '',
    20 => '',
    22 => '',
    21 => '',
    78 => '',
    132 => '',
    90 => '',
    118 => '',
    64 => '',
    11 => '',
    36 => '',
    114 => '',
    17 => '',
    40 => '',
    96 => '',
    92 => '',
    49 => '',
    113 => '',
    44 => '',
    155 => '',
    8 => '',
    152 => '',
    26 => '',
    3 => '',
    2 => '',
    77 => '',
    93 => '',
    130 => '',
    71 => '',
    115 => '',
    83 => '',
    131 => '',
    124 => '',
    7 => '',
    149 => '',
    157 => '',
    24 => '',
    58 => '',
    103 => '',
    125 => '',
    62 => '',
    137 => '',
    99 => '',
    38 => '',
    41 => '',
    128 => '',
    156 => '',
    33 => '',
    94 => '',
    150 => '',
    15 => '',
    67 => '',
    146 => '',
    76 => '',
    29 => '',
    63 => '',
    89 => '',
    18 => '',
    54 => '',
    120 => '',
    53 => '',
    109 => '',
    119 => '',
    28 => '',
    70 => '',
    98 => '',
    121 => '',
    153 => '',
    95 => '',
    80 => '',
    23 => '',
    105 => '',
    85 => '',
    133 => '',
    134 => '',
    136 => '',
    91 => '',
    72 => '',
    140 => '',
    144 => '',
    10 => '',
    129 => '',
    145 => '',
    4 => '',
    65 => '',
    34 => '',
    147 => '',
    73 => '',
    74 => '',
    100 => '',
    112 => '',
    101 => '',
    102 => '',
    66 => '',
    106 => '',
    68 => '',
    69 => '',
    31 => '',
    37 => '',
    81 => '',
    88 => '',
    50 => '',
    16 => '',
    59 => '',
    154 => '',
    19 => '',
    111 => '',
    97 => '',
    9 => '',
    86 => '',
    43 => '',
    51 => '',
    107 => '',
    108 => '',
    126 => '',
    139 => '',
    42 => '',
    143 => '',
    75 => '',
    117 => '',
    104 => '',
    151 => '',
    47 => '',
    141 => '',
    52 => '',
    79 => '',
    82 => '',
    135 => '',
    1 => '',
  ),
  'how_display_items' => 'checked',
  'columns_number' => '3',
)
```

Comment: thanks for replaying, actually i am trying to fetch data from the database. when i try to use your code i got error, bellow my query
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
                        
                        foreach ($retrieve_data as $key => $myvalue) {
                          
                           $properties = get_object_vars($myvalue);

                           print_r($properties);
                           
                           
                           
                        }

Comment: Please can you update your question. Is print_r($properties); returning the array from your question?